# HTMLUnit remove logs

Tags: logging, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, htmlunit-driver

How can I avoid `HtmlUnitDriver` creating logs? With the default configuration a lot of unnecessary logs are created. For example:

```
SEVERE: HtmlSpan[<span class="elementClass">] -> HtmlHtml[<html>]
```

I've tried with the advice from this site http://orjantaule.blogspot.com/2011/11/silencing-logging-output-from.html (Adding a commons-logging.properties file and a simplelog.properties file) but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Just found a solution groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/selenium-users/s29dz03bEyU :

"ClickGuy":

"Until the Selenium team, use this temporary fix.

```
System.setErr(new PrintStream(new OutputStream() {
    public void write(int b) {
    }
}));"
```